# How to fill input element with data-bind attribute programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

The website page has this element:

```html
<input data-bind="attr:{'id': field.name,
                  'name': field.name,
                  'type': field.type() || 'text',
                  'readonly': field.readonly() ? 'readonly' : null,
                  'autocomplete': params.withoutAutoFill ? 'off' : (params.autofill || '')},
            event:{'keypress':field.keypress, 'keyup':field.keyup, 'change': field.change, 'focusin': field.focusin},
            textInput: field.value" id="name" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="">
```

I need to fill text into it programmatically (via Tampermonkey)

I have tried the following methods:

1. Just setting value attribute: `input_.setAttribute('value', 'some text');` - this shows the text but when submitting the form the website says that the field is empty.
2. Simulating keydown/keypress/keyup with this: `input_.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 't'}));` - nothing is entered in the field and it remains empty.
3. Simulating keydown/keypress/keyup with jQuery: `$(input_).trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {keycode: keyCode}));`

None of this or similar code worked. The website swears that the field is empty. How can I send text to this field so that the website thinks it's typed on the keyboard?

Comment: Provide code about form not just input element

Comment: Try execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: Maybe there is an event listener on the input element that transfers the entered value to some other place that is then submitted? Without seeing the actual code we cannot possibly know.

Comment: This `data-bind` attribute looks like it was set on purpose by some *other* javascript library or framework. Identifiy that library (perhaps you already know which one it is ?) and read the doc to see what you should do to correctly update the state of your form.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot it worked! How can I mark this as the answer?